# Why can't Java see the interface method?

Tags: java, oop, lambda, interface, callback

I need to connect two Functions and a Consumer.
To do this, I created a new interface FunctionToConsumer in which I implemented the atLast method.

But the atLast method is just not visible.

```
error: cannot find symbol
        someFunc(a.andThen(b).atLast(end));
                                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   method atLast(Consumer<JSONObject>)
  location: interface Function<String,JSONObject>
```

```
        FunctionToConsumer<String, JSONObject> a = (result) -> {
            JSONObject toReturn = null;
            try {
                JSONObject toReturn = new JSONObject((String) result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return toReturn;
        };

        FunctionToConsumer<JSONObject, JSONObject> b = (result) -> {
            return result;
        };
        
        Consumer<JSONObject> end = (result) ->{
            //some code;
        }
        
        someFunc(a.andThen(b).atLast(end));
```

```
public interface FunctionToConsumer<T, R> extends Function<T, R> {
//    default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<R> after) {
//        Objects.requireNonNull(after);
//        return (T t) -> {after.accept(apply(t));};
//    }
    default Consumer<T> atLast(Consumer<R> consumer) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
        return (T t) -> consumer.accept(apply(t));
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` is of type `Function`, and `Function` does not have a method `atLast(...)`.

Comment: @Turing85 I tried changing the type to FunctionToConsumer, but nothing changes

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the corresponding code.

Comment: Correction: `a` is of type `Function`, but this is only half of the story. The problem is that `Function::andThen` also returns a `Function`.

Comment: How do I implement the andThen method to fix this?

Comment: I fear that this is not easily possible.

Comment: Possible solution: [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/RREWwk).

Comment: @Turinhg85 it's working!